# Sudoku table with a pre-column and a pre-row

Tags: sudoku, logicpuzzle

I would like to have a pre-row and pre-column in a sudoku table. I managed to have these manually (see the below file). But I am not satisfied with my solution.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{sudoku}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\renewcommand*\sudokuformat[1]{\sffamily#1}
\setlength\sudokusize{5cm}


\begin{sudoku}
|6|2|8|5|3|4|9|1|7|.
|5|1|9|8|7|2|4|3|6|.
|4|3|7|9|1|6|2|5|8|.
|8|6|5|2|4|7|1|9|3|.
|3|9|2|1|8|5|7|6|4|.
|7|4|1|6|9|3|5|8|2|.
|2|5|4|3|6|9|8|7|1|.
|1|7|6|4|5|8|3|2|9|.
|9|8|3|7|2|1|6|4|5|.
\end{sudoku}

\large
\vspace{-5.9cm}
\hspace{2.29cm}
$\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
%\hline
\vspace{.125cm}
&1 & 2 &8 &3 &5 &6 & 7& 4& 9 \\
\vspace{.065cm}
9& &  & & & & & && \\
\vspace{.065cm}
4& &  & & & & & && \\
\vspace{.065cm}
3& &  & & & & & && \\
\vspace{.065cm}
8& &  & & & & & && \\
\vspace{.065cm}
5& &  & & & & & && \\
\vspace{.065cm}
6& &  & & & & & && \\
\vspace{.065cm}
7& &  & & & & & && \\
\vspace{.065cm}
2& &  & & & & & && \\
\vspace{.065cm}
1& &  & & & & & && \\
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [logicpuzzle](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/logicpuzzle) (`texdoc logicpuzzle`) package. It supports various puzzles, including some with the need for 'pre columns' like `Skyline`!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{logicpuzzle}
\let\puzzletitleformat\titleformat
\let\titleformat\relax
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
% sffamily
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\sffamily}}
% use scale and fontsize options to change size
\begin{lpsudoku}[scale=.5,fontsize=small]
\setrow{9}{6,2,8,5,3,4,9,1,7}
\setrow{8}{5,1,9,8,7,2,4,3,6}
\setrow{7}{4,3,7,9,1,6,2,5,8}
\setrow{6}{8,6,5,2,4,7,1,9,3}
\setrow{5}{3,9,2,1,8,5,7,6,4}
\setrow{4}{7,4,1,6,9,3,5,8,2}
\setrow{3}{2,5,4,3,6,9,8,7,1}
\setrow{2}{1,7,6,4,5,8,3,2,9}
\setrow{1}{9,8,3,7,2,1,6,4,5}
% use Skyline puzzle commands for 'pre-columns'
\skylineT{1,2,8,3,5,6,7,4,9}
\skylineL{1,2,7,6,5,8,3,4,9}
\end{lpsudoku}
```

\end{document}

[image: sudoku]

Comment: Many thanks, this works perfect. I have to use the package `{titlesec}` in my document, unfortunately there is a conflict with this package.

Comment: @Name Both packages have a `\titleformat` macro. See my edit!

Comment: @Josef You can save the meaning of `\titleformat` by saying `\let\puzzletitleformat\titleformat\let\titleformat\relax`.

Comment: @egreg If logicpuzzle's `titleformat` is still needed, this is of course the cleaner solution.